# Visual Studio 2013 Git tools

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, git-extensions

I have just installed VS2013 in a machine without internet I would like to use the git provider that comes with it for source control but I need features like exporting change sets that I belive are available with third party tools. I've downloaded GitExtensions but it comes with its own git implementation. So, this is my question: 
Is there any way I can make GitExtensions to work with VS2013 git provider? or Is there any way of downloading any third party tools that I can download for manualy install in a disconnected machine?
I'm new to Git so please, be patient.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Juan Carlos

Comment: It's ok.  Good question.  I believe you have to have a repo created on GitHub to use this.  I personally have not used it any other way. Maybe another dev could chime in. Now I have created localized Subversion repos.  I have heard that Source Control is not very good, that may have changed but years back there were some problems with it so I don't blame you for wanting to use Git instead.

Comment: @frank Thanks Frank for your answer, well you can create a local repository and work completely offline. For "advanced operations" you need to download extra tools. My problem is that I can't download from vs because the machine is offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're compatible. GitExtensions and the VS2013 Git provider don't communicate with each other, they each read from and write to the `.git` directory individually, but the way they do so is the same. If you set up (clone or create) your repository using one of them, you can use either of them to do anything with it that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Do I need to install the complete GitExtensions (including its own git provider) or I can install just the GUI without the privider. I did that and I had a lot of missconfigured things in GitExtensions.

Comment: You can use any command-line version of Git, but (IIRC) the VS2013 doesn't come with a command-line version, it uses a library-only version. Personally, I've installed msysgit separately, and set up GitExtensions to use that, but the end result should be the same as when you let the GitExtensions installer install msysgit for you.

Comment: Ok, I read ms git provider is based on msysgit so I imagine I could setup GitExtensions to use ms git provider instead of a separate msysgit installation... is that possible? If not I suppose I will simply install the complete GitExtensions and use it.. is just that it seems not very optimum to me

Comment: "Ok, I read ms git provider is based on msysgit" -- Unless there are multiple versions, no, it's not, it's based on libgit2, as can be seen in the message you get for unexpected errors. Where did you read that it uses msysgit?

Comment: Well you are right, is based on libgit2 (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx) I suppose I got confused. Then I will try to find some GUI for libgit2... will thet work?

Comment: The whole point of my answer is that you don't need to. Let VS2013's own Git provider use libgit2, let GitExtensions use msysgit, and things will work.

Comment: Ok, got it, I just thought if both use the same provider... I guess I will install GitExtensions... there is a GUI for gitlib2 but is not ready yet... I've already mark your answer as an "answer". Thanks